# Krull dimension of surjection

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Let $f \colon R \to S$ be an surjective ring homomorphism (for general rings $R$ and $S$, not necessarily integral domains).
We want to show that $\dim S \leq \dim R$.

My attempt was as following:
The surjective ring homomorphism $f$ induces an injection on the spectra, i.e. an injective map $$\operatorname{Spec} S \to \operatorname{Spec} R.$$ Then we take an arbitrary chain of prime ideals in $S$ and their preimages, which are again prime ideals in $R$. Then since the map on the spectra is injective, no two prime ideals the chain in $S$ can map to the same prime ideal in $R$, so the chain of prime ideals in $R$ is at least as long as the chain in $S$ and hence $\dim S \leq \dim R$. Is this correct or are there any problems I haven't noticed/gaps to fill?

Comment: Sorry... Yes, I have added the question on the bottom.

Comment: Yes, this is a correct proof.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f$ is surjective, $S\cong R/\ker (f)$. Clearly, $\dim (R/\ker (f))\leq \dim (R)$ and so $\dim (S) \leq \dim (R) $.